# How can I save captured images from webcam with different file names in C#

Tags: c#

How can I save images captured from webcam to my `c:/` drive with different file names?

I have been able to capture image webcam and save it on my c:/ drive, but am having slight problems. I want each time an image is saved,it should not overwrite the old captured one already saved on my c:/

(i.e images saved will be different from previous ones left untouched with different names `pix1.jpg`, `pix2.jpg`, `pixs3.jpg`, `pix4.jpg` etc).

Comment: You could also look into generating a unique GUID for each image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method to capture and save to a certain filename, use:

```
string fileName;
int n = 0;

do {
    fileName = "pix" + (++n).ToString() + ".jpg";
} while(System.IO.File.Exists(fileName));
```

Then add `fileName` to the path, and you're done.

Comment: If you do this, I'd make sure you do something to avoid looping/filename checks every time.  E.g. I'd store `n` and reuse it each time.  Maybe let it reset each program start up, but don't let it reset on each call to this method.

Comment: '
                // Save the image as a jpeg.
            //   image.Save("c:\\traffic_light\\image.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.jpg);'

Comment: @DaveChika: Concatenate `fileName` with your path (minus the filename).

Comment: @minitecht,  thanks i was able capture image from my laptop webcam but it saved the pix/images in debug folder in bin. but when i add an external webcam it wouldnt complile but says " an error ocurred while capturing the video image.The video image will now be terminated, Object reference not set to an instance of an Object".

Comment: @DaveChika: That needs to be a new question, as it doesn't have anything to do with this one.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would append a `DateTime` formatted in sortable format to the filename instead of using numbers.

```
string name = "pix";
string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", name, DateTime.Now.ToString("u"));
```

This will give you filenames that look like `pix_201110310834`, `pix_201110310835`, `pix_201110310836`, and so on.

With this approach, you no longer have to worry about using just the right indexes; a DateTime will always keep moving forward.

Notes:

- If you require a shorter interval (milliseconds, maybe), you could
  always just append `DateTime.Now.Ticks` instead.
- Use a neutral timezone if you're concerned about moving across timezones or switching in and out of DST. (`DateTime.UtcNow` is your friend)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot keep track of the current numbered output picture you could look at the currently existing files and determine the maximum number, and add a file with the next number.

```
int max = 0;
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\pictures", "pix*.jpg");
if(files.Any())
  max = files.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.Name)
                                              .Substring("pix".Length)))
             .Max();
string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\pictures", string.Format("pix{0}.jpg", max + 1));
```

Comment: BROKENglass,this is my method for saving image,pls how can i use ur code in my method.pls am a beginner in C#

Comment: public static void SAVEimage(System.Drawing.Image image)
        {
            // Save the image as a jpeg.
            image.Save("c:\\image1.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            
        }